# jcycle prev/next slide visibiilty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcycle

I'm using the jcycle plugin and everything is working the way it should. What I need to do now is some web tracking. So when the user clicks on the next arrow or the previous arrow, I need to know how to check which slide is currently visible so I can pass the right value for web tracking. I hope this makes sense. I really just need to know how to check which slide is currently visibile. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: You'll need to contact the developer or read the documentation provided with the download you purchased. I couldn't find any documentation on their site. Honestly, you should have saved your money and just went with jQuery Cycle. Does everything that one can do, for free, and let's you get at the info you're looking for easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following example markup :

```
<div id="slides">
  <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" style="display: block;">
  <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

This Javascript:

```
$('#slides img').each(function (){
  if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
    //this is your current slide!
  }
});
```

Should provide you with the current element element.

Note that current element has a display: block attribute, and inactive elements are hidden with display: none

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you could use the [`$.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method and the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$("li:visible").index("li");
```

This returns the zero-based index of the visible `li` amongst all other `li`s on the page.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/iquvib/edit

Comment: I have it set up in divs. So I'm having a little trouble making it work. I also need to have it change the url with this call window.history.pushState('Object', 'Title', 'solutions.html?slide=0'); and so forth on the slide number. Let me know if you want to see a snippet of code or anything.

Comment: @Brian the more relevant code you can provide for us the sooner we can get you a good answer :)

Comment: Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/d2kBS/ If you look at the buttons of #goto(insert number here), those function just fine. I need to get the prev/next buttons to do the same thing with the window.history.pushState(). But I also need to check on page load what slide is currently displayed. So when the user clicks on a link from the home page, the url has siturl.com/solutions.html?slide=0 or whatever slide corresponds with the link from the home page. I hope this makes sense.